# Excel Auto Sort

Tags: excel, sorting, vba

Okay so I'm a newbie to VBA (actionscript no problem - so not new to coding, just VBA) and have been working trying learn what I can and get some code to work for me.  I have a report in Excel. Row 6 is the header, 7 blank and 8 is additional information; the actual data begins on row 9 (B9:D9) downwards. Colum C contains the data I'd like to sort by. As new data gets entered in subsequent rows I'd like for the report to automatically re-sort after I've completed the data entry in D#. (Hope this makes sense)

Is this possible in VBA? Or am I asking too much?

Many thanks.

Here's what I've been working with:

```
`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim CCell As Range
Dim ActiveCellInTable As Boolean
Dim r As Single
Dim Value As Variant
Rows("9:38", "B:E").Select
Set CCell = Target
On Error Resume Next
ActiveCellInTable = (CCell.ListObject.Name = "Table2")
On Error GoTo 0
If ActiveCellInTable = True Then
    r = Target.Row - Target.ListObject.Range.Row + 9
    For c = 1 To ActiveSheet.ListObjects(CCell.ListObject.Name).Range.Columns.Count
        If ActiveSheet.ListObjects(CCell.ListObject.Name).Range.Cells(r, c).Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    Next c
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects(CCell.ListObject.Name).Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add _
            Key:=Range("Table2[[#All],[Item number]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order _
            :=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Apply
    End With
End If
End Sub`
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible and here's my version of what you're trying to do.  'Worksheet_Change' has to go in Sheet1 code and will get executed each time any cell in the worksheet changes.   Just to be safe you should disable events otherwise the code could get interrupted prematurely by a different spreadsheet event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim lastRow As Integer
   Dim entireRange As Range, sortRange As Range

   Application.EnableEvents = False

   lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row
   If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D9:D" & lastRow)) Is Nothing Then
     Set entireRange = Range("B9:D" & lastRow)
     Set sortRange = Range("C9:C" & lastRow)

     entireRange.Sort Key1:=sortRange, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
   End If

   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```